# select results from clumon "" and join another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Client

```
ClientID    UserID  CustomerID
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
```

client service:

```
    ClientServiceID   ClientID  ServiceID   Description

    28  10  6           Premium master "multaps1.com"

    48  134 6           Premium master "multaps3.com"

    58  135 6           Premium master "multaps4.com"

    68  137 6           Premium master "multaps5.com"

        366 273 1           Webhosting master "multaps10.com"
```

HostingAccount:

```
    HostingAccountID     Domain DomainIP      Username  Email

   2        multaps1.com         7    Bert    Bert@in.com
    3       multaps2.com         9    Bernard     nard.@Sedn.ca
    4       multaps3.com         3    Bree       Aenean@Cum.org
    5       explts.com       1    exploi   ante@cursusluctus.edu
    6       multaps5.com    10    Rama   quis@tempusrisusuk
```

Service

```
ServiceID  ServiceType
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
```

I have the folowing tables 
I need to get  results like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|CustomerID| Description               | Domain      | UserName | Email   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   | Premium master "multaps1.com" | multaps1.com| Bert| Bert@in.com  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   | Premium master "multaps2.com" | multaps2.com| Bernard| nard@Sedn |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   | Premium master "multaps3.com" | multaps3.com| Bree   | Aan@C.org |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerID,
                               CS.Description,
                               HA.Email,
                               HA.Domain,
                               HA.UserNam
                           FROM ClientService AS CS
                           INNER JOIN Client AS C ON C.ClientID=CS.ClientID
                           LEFT JOIN Service As S
                           ON CS.ServiceID = S.ServiceID
                           LEFT JOIN HostingAccount AS HA
                           On HA.Domain = ANY (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(Description, LOCATE( '"', Description )+1,
                               ( CHAR_LENGTH( Description) - LOCATE('"',REVERSE(`Description`) ) -
                               LOCATE('"',Description)))
                                   from ClientService
                                   )
                                   WHERE S.ServiceType IN (1, 2, 3)
                           ORDER BY HA.HostingAccountID DESC
```

I keep getting multiple time same Domain, username, email and it matches with other rows like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |CustomerID| Description               | Domain      | UserName | Email   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  1   | Premium master "multaps1.com" | multaps1.com| Bert| Bert@in.com  |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  2   | Premium master "multaps2.com" | multaps1.com| Bert| Bert@in.com|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  2   | Premium master "multaps3.com" | multaps1.com| Bert   | Bert@in.com|
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It does this also for other rows to. the problem I need to get description between "" and then get same result as domain. that is the only way they are related and I cant change tables indexes. I don't know how to explain any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JOIN` condition seems overcomplicated. Try this instead:

```
LEFT JOIN HostingAccount AS HA ON  CS.Description LIKE CONCAT('%', HA.Domain, '%')
```

This will return a match as soon as `Domain` is contained within the `Description`.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QZZDUV2582)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I was suposed to check value between "", it is a big database and sometimes there are moore than 1 domain in description. It is hard to explain but I need get the value between "" and  get matched result in domain.

Comment: My substring does get the value between "" but matching with domain doesnt work. I think th eproblem is because I use  ANY (SELECT but iamnot sure if I dont use  ANY it give error Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: @user2268276 Can you provide an example of a string with multiple domains. It is most helpful when the sample data provided elucidate the *actual* issue.

Comment: I used my query and the in where like this: Where CS.Description LIKE CONCAT('%', HA.Domain, '%'). Iam getting same results. Is het ok to use like this

Comment: @user2268276 Are you getting the results you want? If yes, then I guess it's OK!